# Views Bulk Operation alternative?

Tags: 6, views

As VBO for Drupal 6 is outdated due to a security issue, is there an alternative to this module?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find an alternative / replacement for VBO is similar to trying to do so for a module like [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), or other (popular) modules.

To my knowledge there is no other "contributed" module that can do the same as VBO to replace it. Your only alternatives to consider, I think, is either of these options:

1. Carefully review the D6 security issue and check if you can find a way to prevent that issue from happening in your site (do not allow it to be used in any way that might cause the security issue to arise).
2. Spend time to create a fix to actually resolve the D6 security issue in VBO, and optionally consider contributing that back to the VBO module (so that others may help to continue to "maintain" that fix).
3. Similar to "2.", but "hire somebody" to do it for you.

PS: Writing your own "custom" module to replace VBO entirely is another option, but of course "the toughest one" also ...